# Hadoop distcp command says can't connect to server

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs

I want to download data form S3 to HDFS. I tried `s3cmd` but it's not parallel and thus slow. I am trying to make `hadoop distcp` work like this:

```
hadoop distcp -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=[Access Key] -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=[Secret Key] s3n://[account-name]/[bucket]/folder /data
```

but it gives me:

> ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:
>   ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com/[internal-ip]:9001. Already tried 0 time(s)

Answer (score 0):

distcp is a map reduce based job. Make sure job tracker service is start. Try

```
hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
```